# How to explain lrm output

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I am trying to understand how to explain the regression results using lrm() in r. Also, how to export the regression results in Excel.I have five classes of dependent variables. Please see below the results
[image]

Look at scholarly articles

```
lrm(formula = region_5 ~ relative_pt + relative_yt +
relative_ur + relative_cp data = df, x = T, y = T)

Frequencies of Responses

  1       2       3       4       5 
1403840 4428 15399 8098 4703

                       Model Likelihood         Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                             Ratio Test                Indexes          Indexes    
Obs 1436468 LR chi2 229115.98 R2 0.616 C 0.970
max |deriv| 2e-09 d.f. 31 R2(31,1436468)0.147 Dxy 0.941
Pr(> chi2) <0.0001 R2(31,95675.4)0.909 gamma 0.942
Brier 0.006 tau-a 0.042

                        Coef     S.E.   Wald Z  Pr(>|Z|)
y>=2 -20.5013 0.2182 -93.95 <0.0001
y>=3 -21.0916 0.2220 -95.00 <0.0001
y>=4 -23.4748 0.2368 -99.14 <0.0001
y>=5 -25.3832 0.2449 -103.63 <0.0001
relative_pt 1.9706 0.0251 78.41 <0.0001
relative_yt 0.4227 0.0089 47.54 <0.0001
relative_ur 1.3315 0.0778 17.12 <0.0001
relative_cp 0.1378 0.0031 44.74 <0.0001
```

Comment: This is very hard to read. If you use the coding button, you can line things up. 

What part of it confuses you?

And, for exporting to Excel see write.csv .

Comment: Besides declaring this as code as Peter suggested, you did not preserve the original column spacings from the output.  Please re-copy-and-paste and mark as code.  In general, you can get even better output using `options(prType='html')` with the `rms` package but I'm not certain if that can be pasted into pages in this site.